POST carousel of videos on instagram using the graph API
Hey guys so im trying to automate the post on intagram in my app using the api graph from facebook, i already got the single post of pictures and videos of reels, stories, and post, got as well a carousel of pictures but im having a lot of problem trying to make works to POST a carousel that contais or just reels (videos) and mixed onde having reels and pictures, most of the time i pass the process of creating the container for the first video or picture (when mixed) but in the second one usully or i get a timeout or a erro from graph that dont specify nothing or it fails to create the 2 container and pass the status finished, if anyone can help me would be much appreciated !
my code below !

function postOnInstagram($fb, $message, $mediaUrls = [], $isCarrosel = false, $pageAccessToken, $instagramAccountId, $hasVideo = false, $typePost) {
  $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($pageAccessToken);

  try {
      switch ($typePost) {
          case 'post':
              if ($hasVideo) {
                  return $isCarrosel 
                      ? postInstagramMediaCarousel($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message, $mediaUrls)
                      : postInstagramSingleVideo($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message, $mediaUrls[0]);
              } else {
                  return $isCarrosel 
                      ? postInstagramPhotoCarousel($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message, $mediaUrls)
                      : postInstagramSinglePhoto($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message, $mediaUrls[0]);
              }
          case 'reel':
              if (!$hasVideo) {
                  throw new Exception("Reels require a video");
              }
              if ($mediaUrls > 1) {
                return postInstagramMultipleVideos($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message, $mediaUrls);
              }
              else {
                return postInstagramReel($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message, $mediaUrls[0]);
              }
          case 'story':
              if ($hasVideo) {
                  return postInstagramStoryVideo($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message, $mediaUrls[0]);
              } elseif (!empty($mediaUrls)) {
                  return postInstagramStoryPhoto($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message, $mediaUrls[0]);
              } else {
                  return postInstagramStoryText($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message);
              }
          default:
              throw new Exception("Invalid post type");
      }
  } catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
      return 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  } catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
      return 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      return 'General error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

function postInstagramMediaCarousel($fb, $instagramAccountId, $message, $mediaUrls) {
    $mediaIds = [];

    foreach ($mediaUrls as $mediaUrl) {
        sleep(10);

        // Detect media type based on URL or other means
        $mediaType = (preg_match('/\.(mp4)$/i', $mediaUrl)) ? 'VIDEO' : 'IMAGE';

        // Create the media and get the creation ID
        $creationId = createMediaInsta($fb, $instagramAccountId, $mediaUrl, $mediaType);
        if (!$creationId) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create media: $mediaUrl");
        }

        // Wait for the media to be ready
        if (!waitForMediaToBeReadyInsta($fb, $creationId)) {
            throw new Exception("Media is not ready: $creationId");
        }

        $mediaIds[] = $creationId;
    }
   
    // Create carousel with the obtained media IDs
    $carouselResponse = $fb->post("/$instagramAccountId/media", [
        'caption' => $message,
        'media_type' => 'CAROUSEL',
        'children' => $mediaIds,
    ]);
 
    $carouselCreationId = $carouselResponse->getDecodedBody()['id'];
    if (!$carouselCreationId) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to create carousel.");
    }

    // Wait for the carousel to be ready
    if (!waitForMediaToBeReadyInsta($fb, $carouselCreationId)) {
        throw new Exception("Carousel is not ready: $carouselCreationId");
    }

    sleep(30);

    // Publish the carousel
    return publishMedia($fb, $instagramAccountId, $carouselCreationId);
}


function createMediaInsta($fb, $instagramAccountId, $mediaUrl, $mediaType) {
    // Configura o payload dependendo do tipo de mídia
    $payload = [
        'media_type' => $mediaType,
        'is_carousel_item' => 'true'
    ];

    if ($mediaType === 'VIDEO') {
        $payload['video_url'] = $mediaUrl;
    } else {
        $payload['image_url'] = $mediaUrl;
    }

    $response = $fb->post("/$instagramAccountId/media", $payload);

    return $response->getDecodedBody()['id'];
}

function waitForMediaToBeReadyInsta($fb, $creationId, $timeout = 300, $interval = 10) {
    $start = time();
    do {
        sleep($interval);

        try {
            $response = $fb->get("/$creationId");
            $status = $response->getDecodedBody()['status'];
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Log the exception and continue waiting
            error_log("Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        if ($status === 'READY') {
            return true;
        }

        if (time() - $start > $timeout) {
            error_log("Timeout: Media not ready in time.");
            return false;
        }
    } while (true);
}

function publishMedia($fb, $instagramAccountId, $creationId) {
  return $fb->post("/$instagramAccountId/media_publish", [
      'creation_id' => $creationId
  ])->getDecodedBody();
}

i tried everything that i could find on docs and net but cant find a solution!

It seems that everyone is experiencing the same issue, so the problem is likely on Instagram's end, not yours.
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1270072723978459/
There are a lot of threads about all the instagram bugs right now because access_token was also not working but its been fixed.

i will keep a eye on that thread!
